# Way to make screen-readers ignore content-desc

Tags: android, screen-readers, appium

Is there a way to make screen-readers ignore some content-descriptions on android?

I'm currently using appium to test an android-app, finding elements by content-description is easiest AFAIK. The problem is that I want to set content description on pretty much every element, but since screen-readers use these and read them out it would get hideous when using them. Is there a way to solve this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to make screen-readers ignore some content-descriptions on android?

No, sorry. The primary point of `android:contentDescription` is to support screen readers. Use by testing tools like **`uiautomator`** is secondary.